# Can you be blinded by expecto patronum?

Tags: harry-potter

Can you be blinded by expecto patronum?

Like if you happen to stand in the direction the spell is cast?

Comment: 'Time Travel Harry' casts a Patronus charms directly toward his younger self in Prisoner of Azkaban. He doesn't appear to go blind

Comment: Why do you think this might even be a possibility?

Comment: @Anthony Grist, the wand may be right in front of your eyes, perhaps a few inches away. But I don't know about the blinding part either . . .

Answer (score 0):

The light of a patronus is at times referred to as "blinding". For example, in Chapter Twenty of *Prisoner of Azkaban*:

> The blinding light was illuminating the grass around him.

However, I don't believe that there is mention of anyone suffering permanent blindness from exposure to a patronus. On the other hand, there are certainly examples where the blindingness of the light *temporarily* affected someone's vision. For example, in Chapter Nineteen of *Deathly Hallows*:

> He screwed up his eyes as the light became blinding, the trees in front of it pitch-black in silhouette, and still the thing came closer....

Or back in Chapter Twenty of *Prisoner of Azkaban*:

> And out of the end of his wand burst, not a shapeless cloud of mist, but a blinding, dazzling, silver animal. He screwed up his eyes, trying to see what it was.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that both of those examples were at night.  IIRC, the scene with the Patronuses in the Room of Requirements didn't mention them being dangerously or even unusually bright.

Answer (score 0):

## They can “dazzle” but won’t damage eyes.

It is possible for the bright light from a Patronus to overwhelm people’s eyes for a bit - when the Muggle-borns in the Ministry see the Patronuses, they’re dazzled by their light.

> “It’s been decided that you should all go home and go into hiding with your families,’ Harry told the waiting Muggle-borns, who were dazzled by the light of the Patronuses, and still cowering slightly. ‘Go abroad if you can. Just get well away from the Ministry. That’s the – er – new official position. Now, if you’ll just follow the Patronuses, you’ll be able to leave from the Atrium.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 13 (The Muggle-Born Registration Commission)*</sup></sub>

Despite that, looking directly at a Patronus, even one that’s close by, isn’t usually enough to blind, and is certainly never implied to be dangerous. Casting a Patronus in another’s direction wouldn’t do them any harm. Mr. Weasley’s Patronus lands in front of Harry, Ron, and Hermione, and though they do look directly at it while it’s fairly close, the three of them aren’t harmed in any way by looking at it.

> “Then Hermione shrieked: Harry drew his wand again and spun round to see a silver Patronus soar through the drawing-room window and land upon the floor in front of them, where it solidified into the weasel that spoke with the voice of Ron’s father.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 9 (A Place to Hide)*</sup></sub>

Therefore, though it’s possible for the bright light of a Patronus to momentarily dazzle and make it harder to see for a brief time, it wouldn’t truly “blind” them or damage their eyes.

Comment: A brilliant answer. This specifically answers the question of its brightness, approx 1000-1600 lumens is a "dazzling" light but not blinding

Comment: @Valorum Thanks a lot! :)